Wordpress Text in Table Doesn't Match Rest of Post
I am making a post template that includes a rather large and complicated table.  When editing in the classic editor 'visual' mode, everything looks like it matches.  However, when it is published, the text does not match up at all.  See screen grabs for example of current issue.  Below is the code Copy and pasted.
<table class="table2" border="1" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100%"><colgroup> <col style="width: 50%;" span="1" /> <col style="width: 50%;" span="1" /> </colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> LOG DATE:</td>
<td> [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Log-Date"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> CHASE VEHICLE:</td>
<td> [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Chase-Vehicle"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> CHASE PARTNERS:</td>
<td> [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Chase-Partners"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> TARGET REGION:</td>
<td> [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Target-Region"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> MILES DRIVEN</td>
<td> [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Chase-Miles"]</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table class="table2" border="0" width="50%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">SPC OUTLOOK: [xyz-ips snippet="ACF-SPC-Outlook"]
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">TORNADO</td>
<td align="center">HAIL</td>
<td align="center">WIND</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-SPC-Tornado"]</td>
<td align="center">[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-SPC-Hail"]</td>
<td align="center">[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-SPC-Wind"]</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="table2" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>TORNADOES SEEN:</td>
<td>[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Tornado"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HAIL ENCOUNTERED:</td>
<td>[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Hail"]"</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Published View
Wordpress Visual Editor
Have attempted to make tweaks in the CSS style sheet where a table was defined by adding a second table class.  No changed made to published post.
    /*table*/
table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 80%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 1em 0.8em 0.8em 0.8em;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
th {
    border-top: none;
}

/*table for chase logs*/
table2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.2);
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
th {
    border-top: none;
}


Is your theme lacking some CSS settings? I guess you've inspected in the browser devtools to see exactly what CSS is being applied and from where?

You may want to update this line:
Before:
<table class="table2" border="1" width="100%">

After:
<table class="table2" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

This way the .table2 class can be responsible for the table's styling, where you already declare the width.
Also you have an additional quotation for the HAIL ENCOUNTERED xyz-ips snippet field, so remove that.
Before:
<td>[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Hail"]"</td>

After:
<td>[xyz-ips snippet="ACF-Hail"]</td>

That should be a good starting point to fixing up whatever mismatch issue you're facing.

Thanks Grant.  I have made the tweaks.  The border did eliminate the border issue, but the class=table2 is pulling the 80% text size from table.
I guess the problem as I narrow this down is more about creating a table with it's own CSS style verses the default that came with the theme.

And I removed the quotation (it was meant to print as 0.00" for measurement.
